# Android Virtual Display

Tags: java, android, virtual

I am doing a project where I need to hide app interactions in the background and only show the results to the user. Is it possible using the [Virtual Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay.html)?

And also with the VirtualDisplay can I create a display and assign it to a particular application?

I did not find any suitable examples so far. A good example will be very much appreciated ti illustrate how to use VirtualDisplay and its main purpose.

Comment: If what you want is possible from an ordinary Android SDK app, that would be a substantial security flaw in Android.

Comment: Yes I know that. The main thing I am looking forward to knowing virtual displays and their usage in Android. Can you describe me a scenario?

Comment: Virtual displays underlie the `Presentation` system and the `MediaProjection` system, as I understand it.